# Saber el tipo de datos de un campo de una tabla FireBird

Tags: sql, firebird

estoy trabajando en una base de datos de firebird  y necesito hacer una consulta de los tipos de datos que tiene las tablas, en SQL Server esta esta consulta para saber los tipos de dato de una tabla:

```
Select  * from information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME='EJEMPLO'
```

¿conocen algún equivalente de dicha consulta en firebird?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la tabla **`RDB$FIELDS`**.

En esa tabla tienes el campo **`RDB$FIELD_TYPE`**, con el cual puedes obtener el tipo del campo.

Este campo te devolverá un valor entero correspondiente a los que se ven a continuación:

```
7 = SMALLINT
8 = INTEGER
10 = FLOAT
12 = DATE
13 = TIME
14 = CHAR
16 = BIGINT
27 = DOUBLE PRECISION
35 = TIMESTAMP
37 = VARCHAR
261 = BLOB
```

Para el tipo **`BLOB`**, hay otro campo de la tabla que te dará el subtipo (**`RDB$FIELD_SUB_TYPE`**).

Código

```
SELECT
    R.RDB$FIELD_NAME  AS NombreColumna,
    F.RDB$FIELD_TYPE  AS TipoColumna
FROM
     RDB$RELATION_FIELDS R
 LEFT JOIN
     RDB$FIELDS F ON R.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE = F.RDB$FIELD_NAME
WHERE
    R.RDB$RELATION_NAME='CARTERA'
ORDER BY
    R.RDB$FIELD_POSITION
```